# Where to start my bookmark extension for Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to make a new extension for Firefox, My idea is to use JavaScript, I already made the thing for chrome.

I tried to Google for some tutorial on how to start with my extension, but I didn't find anything structured/understandable.

1. I need tutorials on how to build the interface, if there is any
   possibility to use html & JavaScript for that task, just like Google
   chrome.
2. I need a tutorial which would explain me how to access and modify the bookmarks on Firefox

Basically, I need help on where to start.

Comment: 'Where to start' questions are not a good fit for this site. Usually Google can help with these kind of questions.

Comment: @KendallFrey thank you pal but as I wrote **"I tried to Google, but I didn't find anything"**, therefore I'm trying to ask somebody that already might have experience & know more than me on that matter, and that could maybe explain me a little bit around, and/or guide me to some good references.

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.11/

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for (via a google search)

http://blog.nparashuram.com/2011/10/writing-browser-extensions-comparing.html

http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=511

Comment: Here is the getting started tutorial from the SDK's docs:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/index.html#getting-started

In addition to SO, you can also ask questions on the [google group / mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mozilla-labs-jetpack) as well as in the #jetpack channel on irc.mozilla.org

Comment: I ended up using Jetpack which is the most similar to the Google Chrome Extensions API, Well, not exactly but surely isn't XPI, which is a real headache.